# Using GA to retrieve metrics from API

Tags: node.js, rest, google-analytics

I am trying to use Google Analytics to retrieve metrics from an API.
The thing is, I am not sure to understand how the whole analytics tracking works. I tried to understand how to implement custom metrics and dimensions from this : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events but I am still not very sure on how to proceed.

Let us say for instance that I want to send a custom event to Analytics when a client clicks on a button to create a PDF.

Should I write something like :
     ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Project',
  eventAction: 'pdf_export',
  eventLabel: 'StartOfProject'
});

And put it in the handler of the endpoint route corresponding to the page launched when the button is clicked?

Or do I have to create an event with EventEmitter? I must confess I am quite lost here...

[EDIT] Victor Leontyev showed a very easy way to of it (thank you!), however it was here a rather simple use case. I was also wondering :

1. If I want to send a custom metric (a ratio...), should I put it in the optional eventValue?
2. If I want to have the number of PDF (to keep with the same example) per day, how can I do? It would mean I guess that I should launch an event every 24H on a precise hour, and have kept somewhere (in a DB?) the data for the day so I can send it? Can this easily be done?
3. The other kind of metrics I need would be periods between two actions, lie let us say between the click on the 'Create a new PDF' button and a 'Print the PDF' one. Can it be done with launching a tier on the first button press, then stopping it and the second one and sending the time as the eventValue ? Or is it more complicated?

I warmly thank you once again for any lead/form of hep and support!

Have a nice day,

-- smgr

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button, where users can download your PDF. For example:

```
<a href="/abc/bcd/linkto.pdf">Download PDF</a>
```

And if you want to send event to GA with this data:

- eventCategory: 'Project'
- eventAction: 'pdf_export'
- eventLabel: 'StartOfProject'

All that you need is to change HTML of your button into:

```
<a href="/abc/bcd/linkto.pdf" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Project', 'pdf_export', 'StartOfProject');">Download PDF</a>
```

Then you will be able to see how many users click to your `Download PDF` button in GA (`Behavior -> Events` or `Realtime -> Events`)

Comment: Thank you very much for the precise and concise answer! I personally mainly work on the server endpoints rather than on the HTML front end part of the API, is it possible from there as well or not?

Comment: It is possible to do in the backend with some limitations, but easiest and  best way is to do that is frontend

Comment: Would it be as an input in the handler? I guess anyway I will try to get my 
hands on the front end, thank you so much :) I edited my original post to add a few more specific questions, if you have any form of answer for these as well I would be extremely grateful.